# How to speed these code,which is used to find matching record from two grid boths have 190000+ records

Tags: c#

say i have two grid each contain 190000+ records ,named grid_A and grid_B,

for every record in grid_A ,i want to find whether there is a same record in grid_B.

grid_A and grid_B have same columns ,in my case,their columns is

col1    col2    col3    col4

and their datatype may  be

string   datatime double

by now,what i do is:

for each row in grid_A,loop through all rows in  grid_B,and compare the Four cols

one by one.

the code is shown blow:

```
        //loop grid_A
        foreach (UltraGridRow row in ultraGrid1.Rows)
        {
             List<object> lo = new List<object>();

             for (int i=0;i<4;i++)              //add col's value to ListA
             {
                  lo.Add(row.Cells[i].Value);
             }
             //loop grid_B
             foreach (UltraGridRow rowDist in ultraGrid2.Rows)
             {
                  List<object> loDist = new List<object>();
                  for (int ii=0;ii<4;ii++)              //add col's value to ListB
                  {
                       loDist.Add(rowDist.Cells[ii].Value);
                  }

                  if (CompareList(lo, loDist) == true)     //compare two List
                  {
                     break;
                  }
             }
        }




        //  the function compare two List
        private bool CompareList(List<object> a, List<object> b)
        {
             //Assert a.count==b.count
             for (int i=0;i<a.Count;i++)
             {
                   if (!CompareObject(a[i], b[i]))
                        return false;
             }

             return true;
        }


        //
        private bool CompareObject(object oa, object ob)
        {

              // object is string
              if (oa.GetType() == typeof(System.String))
              {
                    try
                    {
                            string strOb = Convert.ToString(ob);
                            if (oa.ToString() == strOb)
                                return true;
                            else
                                return false;
                     }
                     catch
                    {
                           return false;
                    }
                }
               // object is datetime
               if (oa.GetType() == typeof(System.DateTime))
               {
                      try
                      {
                         DateTime dtOb = Convert.ToDateTime(ob);
                         if ((DateTime)oa == dtOb)
                            return true;
                         else
                            return false;

                      }
                      catch
                      {
                         return false;
                      }
               }
               //object is double
               if (oa.GetType() == typeof(System.Double))
               {
                    try
                    {
                         double ddOb = Convert.ToDouble(ob);
                         if ((double)oa == ddOb)
                            return true;
                         else
                             return false;

                     }
                    catch
                   {
                        return false;
                   }
              }

            return true;

        }
```

i know my compare way is too stupid,in fact,each loop circel cost 2.4 seconds,
that is :190000 circels cost 130 hours,it looks so terrible,
i heard it can use hash table to speed search performance,but i do not know how to use it.
anyway,for each record in grid_A ,search all record in grid_B is unacceptable,
so whatever help is appreciate.

my grid's data is imported from excel,so it does not have sql database or table.

Comment: how often is your data changed?

Comment: is `ii` a bug or typing mistake, notice that you later use just `i`?`for (int ii=0;i<4;i++)              //add col's value to ListB
                  {
                       loDist.Add(rowDist.Cells[ii].Value);
                  }`

Comment: it is a typing mistake,i  have modified it .

Comment: Where is your data originating from, if SQL-based, it would probably be better to just run a query between the two like sources of data.

Comment: my data is imported from excel

Comment: you can inport your data from excel to sql

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find out whether in grid_B there is a record the same as in grid_A. Instead of doing nested `foreach` (resulting in O(n^2) complexity, which is huge) you could change your algorithm.

If you would first iterate over `grid_B` and calculate hashes of each row (e.g. by combining the data into string form, and then taking hash value, but there might be better way of generating the hash). If you would put those hashes into dictionary as a key, and value could be reference to row in `grid_B` or some other value needed.
Then you could iterate over `grid_A`, calculate hash value of row and check in dictionary whether the key is present or not. If it is present - you have the same row in `grid_B` (and the value stored in dictionary may lead you to that row for example). If it is not present - there is no row with the same values.

Such approach will give you complexity of O(2n), which is usually simplified to just O(n) - we will always have two iterations over the data. Thisis significant improvement, but at the cost of higher memory consumption.
Whether such approach is faster may depend on number of records in grids, but given you have 190k records - that should be faster (though I cannot test that now, will try to do that in the evening).

Comment: thank you for your advise,I try to add a Dictionary<int,int>,which key is hashcode of combine data,value is the row index of grid_B.

Comment: by this way,it do significent improve code's perfermence.the problem is ,different combine data may generate same hashcode ,but this can be resolved by addtional check.so,your solution is still very valuable,it help me so much,thank you.

Comment: If the combined data is not exactly the same then chances of hash collision are pretty low. That's the whole idea of hash - even very simillar data (like 1 character is different) generates very different hash value). Still - collisions may happen and additional checks may be usefull, but will be rare

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort both of the grids beforehand, you can greatly reduce the number of comparisons. You would maintain a current row index for each grid (`row_A` for `grid_A`, `row_B` for `grid_B`) and walk your way through the grids. For each comparison (pseudocode):

```
if (grid_A[row_A] < grid_B[row_B])
    row_A++;

if (grid_A[row_A] == grid_B[row_B])
{
    //    matching record
    row_A++;
    row_B++;
}

if (grid_A[row_A] > grid_B[row_B])
    row_B++;
```

If you are unable to sort the grids then I'm not aware of a way to avoid your current algorithm. You'll just have to optimize the individual row comparisons as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hand on the raw data and not through the datagrid, this way you will not have the overhead of the ultraGrid and it will speed up the things a bit.

An other idea would be to create a string out of each and every row and compare these two strings. e.g. if the row is 1,'text', true, 1/1/2001 then  you must create and ordered list containing the string '1-text-true-1/1/2001' this way you will have a much faster indexing.